IIFE is not giving any output
I tried IIFE in js, but its not giving any output
if I am not executing any other part of the code in the program except this function(using node)

When I tried executing or printing any other thing too with this function then only it gave me results.Expecting the function to be exectued and would give results but it didnt return anything in output if I have executed it without printing anything above using console.log()?

Don't share image. Edit your question and paste your code-block.

add a leading ! or ; before the IIFE

Start adding semicolons to your code right now and avoid such problems in the future. No semicolon vs with semicolon
